# Core data sort objects by date not producing expected output

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I am trying to display objects based on the time they were created. Each object is a NSManagedObject with a dateCreated property. I wrote the code below:

```
NSFetchRequest * request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *e = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyObject" inManagedObjectContext:context];
request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dateCreated" ascending:NO]];
request.entity = e;
NSError * error;
NSArray* result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
for (MyObject* object in result) {
     NSLog(@"%@", @([object.dateCreated timeIntervalSince1970]));
}
```

and here is the output:

```
2018-03-06 08:55:06.591 1520326503.972214
2018-03-06 08:55:06.591 1520326503.995906
2018-03-06 08:55:06.592 1520326504.012891
2018-03-06 08:55:06.592 1520326504.002804
2018-03-06 08:55:06.592 1520326503.989189
2018-03-06 08:55:06.592 1520326504.009239
2018-03-06 08:55:06.592 1520326503.964928
2018-03-06 08:55:06.592 1520326503.968894
```

i.e. there are not sorted. I checked that the dates output are correct (i.e. as expected) but the order is not. If I sort by another key (e.g. name) code is fine so I thought the request was correctly being set. Also, the following code correctly sorts the resulting array:

```
result = [result sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(MyObject*  _Nonnull obj1, MyObject*  _Nonnull obj2) {
    return [obj2.dateCreated compare:obj1.dateCreated];
}];
```